# Extract RGB plane in iOS xcode swift4

Tags: image-processing

I need to do following:-
1. Extract R,G,B plane from a color image 
2. After doing all calculation superimpose planes and get color image back.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: What have you done now? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: What I actually have to do is, obtain a multiplier from image captured from different camera using a known value, then apply the multiplier to the each r,g,b plane of image. I have obtained multiplier so far, i searched a lot on how to extract planes individually but failed. Could you help me out?